# Search Results: Differentiate posts and pages

Tags: search, conditional-tags

Currently the search results are all shown in the same way, no matter if it's a post or a static page. 
As I don't want the comment count and the categories to show up for static pages, I was wondering how to do it.

The code: **(Update October 22nd)**

```
<?php   
if(get_post_type() == 'page') : ?>
  <div class="recent_postMetaSingle">
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/eye.png" alt="Views" title="views" /> <?php print_page_views(get_the_ID('')); ?> 
<p>This is a static page!</p></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="recent_postMetaSingle">
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/eye.png" alt="Views" title="views" /> <?php print_page_views(get_the_ID('')); ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comments2.png" alt="Comments" title="comments" /> <?php comments_popup_link('0', '10', '%'); ?> 
</div>
<div class="recent_category"><?php the_category(' // ') ?></div>
```

Thanks for your help so far. I updated the code.
Now, it only shows up on static pages, but the HTML markup below the conditional tag also shows up and I want that to only show up for posts.
I guess I have to put an "else" tag somewhere? I just don't know how to implement it correctly.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think you're on the right tracking using `get_post_type()`. Of course, if you use `!= 'page'` it shows up on posts and not on pages. Could you clarify the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Hm, well what you see in the second code snippet is what I want to show ONLY if it's a static page, but not a post, so how would I have to modify the code above in order to achieve that? :)

Comment: if(get_post_type() == 'page'):

Comment: @EarnestoDev: Hello. That worked fine. Now, I still need to figure out how to implement it correctly. Please see my updated quesiton. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if(get_post_type() == 'page'): // Only pages ?>
    <div class="recent_postMetaSingle">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/eye.png" alt="Views" title="views" />
        <?php print_page_views(get_the_ID('')); ?> 
        <p>This is a static page!</p></div>
<?php elseif(get_post_type() == 'post'): // If not page, Only posts ?>
    <div class="recent_postMetaSingle">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/eye.png" alt="Views" title="views" />
        <?php print_page_views(get_the_ID('')); ?>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comments2.png" alt="Comments" title="comments" />
        <?php comments_popup_link('0', '10', '%'); ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="recent_category"><?php the_category(' // ') ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_page('your_static_page_slug'))
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. I tried it the following way: `<?php  
if (is_page('  <div class="recent_postMetaSingle">
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/eye.png" alt="Views" title="views" /> <?php print_page_views(get_the_ID('')); ?> 
<p>This is a static page!</p></div>'))
?>
<?php endif; ?>`  However this outputs a syntax error (unexpected T_STRING). I tried it in a different way and this works better, but I still have a small issue. Please see my updated question, thank you :)